# Find domains that are not followed by a closing span tag

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to regex domains out of some text. I want to ignore domains that are followed by a `</span>` tag.

For example given the following input:

```
matchme.com<span>dontmatchme.com</span>
```

I would like my matches to contain one item:

```
matchme.com
```

I tried the following:

```
(?:[A-Za-z0-9|-]+\.*[A-Za-z0-9|-]+\.[a-z]+)(?!<\/span)
```

The issue with the above is that the negative lookahead simply means that the second item in the input is cut short and still considered valid:

```
matchme.com
dontmatchme.co
```

I have a regex101 here https://regex101.com/r/FpWomQ/1

Comment: any feedback on the downvote?

Comment: The neg. lookahead is satisfied between `.co` `m` because there is no `</span` ahead. You'd need possessive quantifiers (not available in python regex) or add a word boundary `\b`. [See your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpWomQ/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regular expression:

`[a-z.]+(?=<\/span>)|([a-z.]+)(?=<[\/a-z]+>)`

The regular expression uses alternation to only capture domains which are not followed by `</span>`.

- `[a-z.]+` Match as many alphabetic or `.` characters as possible.
- `(?=<\/span>)` Positive lookahead for `</span>`.
- `|` Alternation (OR).
- `([a-z.]+)` Capture group. Match as many alphabetic or `.` characters as possible.
- `(?=<[\/a-z]+>)` Positive lookahead for opening bracket `<`, alphabetic characters or forward slash `/`, closing bracket `>`.

The desired match is contained within the capture group.
You may try the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/7IwClk/3).

Answer (score 1):

Could you possibly change the regex to ignore lines starting with a `<`, if so you could use this regex

```
^[^<]*$
```

Meaning it will match any line that doesn't begin with a `<`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've updated to question to reflect the fact that I can't count on line breaks. I'm parsing HTML and there are cases where there are no line breaks.